# ArcGIS Feature Class based on year

Tags: date, arcgis

I have two feature class in the same geodatabase.  One of the fields is "P_Year".  I would like the objects that are more than 20 years old to be in feature class "GroupA" and all the objects that are less than or equal to 20 years old to be in feature class "Group B".  Is there a way to do this based on the current date? so that 20 year old objects (1995 objects) are automatically moved into feature class "Group A" when we enter 2016.
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an ArcPy script or a ModelBuilder model which:

- Searches old features in GroupB
- Copies them to GroupA
- Removes them from GroupB

Then [schedule](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/) the script or module to run automatically on a predefined date/time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, could you give me an idea of the structure of the ArcPy script please? I have never used that before